# Extended a partition error

Tags: ubuntu, partition, disk, partition-table

I'm trying to extend the main partition to 40G from 30G after modifying the EC2 volume.

This is what I have:

```
xvda                        202:0    0    40G  0 disk 
├─xvda1                     202:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─xvda2                     202:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─xvda5                     202:5    0  29.8G  0 part 
  ├─ser-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  25.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─ser-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

How do I extend the main partition to take the 10 extra Gb?

I've tried `sudo growpart /dev/xvda 3 --dry-run` so that I can extend that 3rd partition to 40

but the result is:

```
NOCHANGE: partition 3 is size 0. it cannot be grown
```

`df-h` returns

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ser-root   26G   18G  6.4G  74% /
udev                         30G  4.0K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       6.0G  280K  6.0G   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         30G     0   30G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvda1                  228M   63M  154M  29% /boot
```

Anyway to extend ser-root to take into account the 10G added?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried `sudo growpart /dev/xvda 3 --dry-run` so that I can extend that 3rd partition to 40

You don't have partition 3, so I assume you want to resize the `xvda5`. That is a logical partition so you need to resize the extended partition `xvda2` first. After that resize the logical partition `xvda5`. You have an LVM setup so if you want to actually use the free space for your root filesystem, you'll also need to resize the LVM physical volume on the `xvda5` partition using `pvresize` (just use `pvresize /dev/xvda5` after resizing the partition, `pvresize` will automatically adjust size of the PV format to the size of the partition). Next you need to resize your `root` logical volume using `lvresize -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ser-root` (`-l +100%FREE` will tell `lvresize` to use all free space, `-r` will resize the filesystem too).

Note: I recommend backing up your data first (you should do that always when changing storage).

Comment: Is this possible to do without interrupting the server?